Azure VM stuck on GRUB Bootloader after kernel upgrade
I've an Azure VM that has had quite a lot of extra work regards its networking etc performed as post-create setup. Having read about a particular vulnerability that the VM was susceptible to (judging by the kernel version) I decided to try upgrading the kernel. Perhaps it worked, perhaps not - at the moment the VM gets stuck while booting. The Boot Diagnostics blade of azure management portal shows a screenshot of the machine as a read-only diagnostic of what the screen looked like at the time of the shot (and an updated screenshot can be requested). It looks like this:

I'd like to find a way to recover the situation without deleting the entire VM and having to start over with the ancillary setup. If I could find a way to "press Enter" that would probably be easiest but I haven't yet found any way to do that and dismiss this bootloader screen.
I'm not averse to wiping the OS Disk and replacing it with an image of Ubuntu 20 (how it was supplied when creating it from athe Azure marketplace) but I haven't found an easy option to do this - I was hoping that either Redeploy or Reapply would perform it, but it seems not.
This failed VM does have another sibling machine that is the same in nearly all regards except it wasn't upgraded. I'm wondering if I can take a snapshot image this other VM somewhere in the Azure portal, and use that snapshot to create a workable disk for the failed VM..
So, my question is:
What can I do, with the limited interface of the azure portal, to get or reset this machine back to a working state so I can SSH into it so I can run the scripts that set it up for our production use ?
Update:
Azure provide a "serial console" that can be used to interact with the instance in most cases, but here it looks like this:

Typing into here seems to have no effect on the bootloader menu

Just pressing enter should boot the system. When it is running you can check the grub config if the normal timeout is disabled.

How does one "Just press enter" when the VM is in a datacenter in another country, and the only access I have to it is through a website? There is a serial console blade on the website, but it doesn't show anything, and pressing enter into it seemingly has no effect

I'm not familiar with Azure per se, but usually you have access to an interactive console, usually via the website. I assumed that's where the screenshot comes from.

I'm a little stumped that Azure only provides a serial console, but that should do the trick.

Per my comment above "There is a serial console blade on the website, but it doesn't show anything, and pressing enter into it seemingly has no effect" but I've updated the question to reflect this. The screenshot comes from a "click here to download a screenshot of what your machine looks like" type diag page - it's not interactive

How did you do the kernel upgrade?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@Guido from within the instance, but I don't remember exactly.. Trying to find the site I referred to while doing it - I remember looking at a list of kernel versions from ubuntu to find a version number after the exploit was fixed, maybe doing something that updated a list of available kernels on the local machine (apt-cache search?) and then running an apt-get command to install it. If I could get into the instance I could look in the shell history, but for now it's been a week since I did it and I've done so much other work on so many different/unrelated things, I've lost the detail

You can try do a repair the VM using powershell, creates a new os disk using Azure cli.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/virtual-machines/linux/repair-linux-vm-using-azure-virtual-machine-repair-commands
